# Add String in a String before ".extention"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table like:

```
ID       NAME
----------------
35       File.png
```

What I want to do is update that record as:

```
ID       NAME
----------------
35     File_35.png
```

I have this:

```
            DECLARE arch_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Id from dbo.Archivos WHERE Nombre LIKE ('%' + @Id_Relacion_Articulo_Archivo + '%')

        OPEN contact_cursor;

        FETCH NEXT FROM arch_cursor  
        INTO @Id_cur

        WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )

        UPDATE dbo.Archivos SET Nombre ...

        CLOSE arch_cursor;  
        DEALLOCATE arch_cursor;
```

I know that STUFF statement can do something like put a string on a specific place of the string, but somebody know how to specify "insert string before "." without losing the left chars too?"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Could you have a file with a name like `My.File.png`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no files can have a `.` in the name (apart from to denote the extension) I find `STUFF` easiest for this:

```
SELECT ID, [Name],
       STUFF([Name], CHARINDEX('.',[Name]),0,CONCAT('_',ID)) AS NewName
FROM (VALUES(35,'File.png'))V(ID,[Name]);
```

If there could be multiple `.` characters and it needs to prior to the last one, you have to use the (expensive) function `REVERSE`:*

```
SELECT ID, [Name],
       STUFF([Name], LEN([Name]) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE([Name]))+1,0,CONCAT('_',ID)) AS NewName
FROM (VALUES(35,'File.png'),(36,'File.2.png'))V(ID,[Name])
```

*Also, **don't** loop. Just do this in a set based method. You're using a RDBMS, not a Programming Language:*

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET File = STUFF([Name], CHARINDEX('.',[Name]),0,CONCAT('_',ID));
```

Comment: Thanks, done like this: UPDATE dbo.Archivos SET Nombre = stuff(Nombre, charindex('.', Nombre),0, '_' + @Id_cur)

Comment: That would result in every row having the same ID part though, @gaccerboni . That isn't the intent here, is it?

Answer (score 3):

```
select id
, concat(left(name, charindex('.', name)-1), '_', id, RIGHT(name,(CHARINDEX('.', name))-1)) NAME
from test
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1708b53a64c80daf9be6acd6f3dc113d)

Also you can do it with a replace:

```
select id
       , replace(name, '.', concat('_',id,'.')) 
from test
```

And here is the one option you can use if you will look from the right (first occurrence of the character '.'):

```
select id
       , concat(substring(name, 1, len(name)-charindex('.', (reverse(name))))
                , '_'
                , id
                , substring(name, len(name)-charindex('.', (reverse(name)))+1, charindex('.', (reverse(name)))))    
from test
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a299b9c69decac8229b0f26c2776ab3e) where you can see all 3 of this examples in action with this two rows of data:

- insert into test values (35, 'File.png')
- insert into test values (55,
  'File.File.png')